# VueJs/Capacitor/html2pdf

Tags: vue.js, capacitor, html2pdf

I want export pdf on my hybrid’s app (android/web app)
The export pdf on web app is ok, but not on android capacitor app.
I read the doc, but many examples are with pdfmake, not html2pdf.js.
Here my function for create a pdf in my component Vue.js :

Error : /storage/emulated/0/Documents/FL_19-11-2021_10-06-50.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

manisfest.xml :

```
    <!-- Permissions -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Vue.js :

import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core'

import { Filesystem, Directory, Encoding } from '@capacitor/filesystem'

```
async egs2pdf () {
      this.$store.dispatch('setLoading', true, { root: true })
      let egs2PdfComponent = document.getElementById('egs2PdfComponent')
      this.opt.filename = this.patient.patientId

      if (!Capacitor.isNativePlatform()) {
        html2pdf().set(this.opt).from(egs2PdfComponent).save().then(() => {
          this.$store.dispatch('setLoading', false, { root: true })
        })
      } else {
        html2pdf()
          .set(this.opt)
          .from(egs2PdfComponent)
          .outputPdf()
          .then( pdf => {
            Filesystem.requestPermissions()
              .then( permission => {
                if (permission) {
                  this.writeCapacitorFile(pdf)
                    .then(() => {
                      this.$store.dispatch('setLoading', false, { root: true })
                      this.$toast.success("Enregistré dans vos documents !")
                    })
                    .catch(error  => {
                      console.log(error)
                      this.$toast.success("Vidda n'a pas la permission d'accéder à vos documents")
                    })
                }
              })
          })
      }
    },
    async writeCapacitorFile(pdf) {
      await Filesystem.writeFile({
        path: `${this.patient.patientId + '.pdf'}`,
        data: pdf,
        directory: Directory.Documents ,
        encoding: Encoding.UTF8,
      })
      .then(() => {
        return true
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return error
      })
    },
```

Thank you for help ;-)